# Fedora 37 / VSCode - не могу настроить Customize UI

Tags: visual-studio-code, fedora

Кто сталкивался с настройкой Customize UI в VSCode (OS Fedora 37).
Уже втрой день сижу ламаю голову.
Скачал пакет rpm с оф. сайта, установил.
Так как меню редактора очень малеькое (как и почти везде в программах на федоре, несколько дней юзаю ос) хочу настроить размеры проводинка (не через ctrl + ).
Установил Customize UI, вместе с ним установился Monkey patch.
При попытке изменить настройки через Customize редактор говорит что нет связи с Monkey patch, нужно установить зависимости. Кликаю Ок - далее ошибка Monkey, что нету прав на изменения....
Уже замучился, на Винду возвращаться не хочу, но такая проблема на ровном месте очень напрягает, не знаю как ее решить.
Прошу помогите пожалуйтса

Comment: *"меню редактора очень малеькое ... как и почти везде в программах на федоре"* Вот про это бы поподробнее. Почему Ctrl-+ не хочется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На последней версии VSCode Customize UI не работает, попробуй поставить версию ниже 1.78